# Solving a limit equation

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have the following expression
$$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} \omega \left(e^{\frac{1}{2} b \omega^2  t^{2 \kappa} -  a \omega t -\omega x_0} -  e^{\frac{1}{2} b \omega^2  t^{2 \kappa} -  a \omega t}\int_1^t b \kappa u^{2 \kappa-1} g(u) e^{-\frac{1}{2} b \omega^2  u^{2 \kappa} + a \omega u} du \right) = 0,$$
where $a, b, x_0, \kappa$ are arbitrary constants. I am trying to find  the function $g$, is this possible ?
We can rewrite this as 
$$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} \omega e^{\frac{1}{2} b \omega^2  t^{2 \kappa} -  a \omega t }e ^{-\omega x_0} = \lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} \omega e^{\frac{1}{2} b \omega^2  t^{2 \kappa} -  a \omega t}\int_1^t b \kappa u^{2 \kappa-1} g(u) e^{-\frac{1}{2} b \omega^2  u^{2 \kappa} + a \omega u} du $$
and then can obtain
$$\lim_{\omega\rightarrow\infty} \frac{e ^{-\omega x_0}}{b \kappa\int_1^t  u^{2 \kappa-1} g(u) e^{-\frac{1}{2} b \omega^2  u^{2 \kappa} + a \omega u} du}= 1.$$
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: i don't see how you can swap limit and integral if the left term depends on $\omega$, not just the integral; especially since it actually is infinite in the limit